# Royal Delivery Service

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

I am at loss. Of the memory!

I remember that I was running with an errand from the King, that I had to take a certain item from the treasury and deliver it to a certain person in the kingdom! Yet silly me - I bumped my head on the ground and forgot the details completely.

The only hint I have left is this weird parchment from inside my pocket:

[image: the parchment]

Please tell me - what could it mean? What was my mission here?

Comment: Bonus question from me: what does the ratio refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial:

The purple symbols can be interpreted by:

> Imagine overlaying each shape with a four sided square; wherever there is an overlap, remove the line completely. What is left are two words UNICORN and LION.

The first:

> Could be a unicorn horn, with the four tally marks suggesting 'horn' as a four letter word.

the second:

> Lion ... Could suggest the king (king of the jungle)? But can't see how the twelve tally marks could fit here.

EDIT:

yep, as pointed out in the comment:

> Unicorn is Scotland's official animal, and the lion is England's, and together they're part of the UK coat of arms. They're also part of a nursery rhyme, in which they fight for a crown, with the lion winning (hence the tally marks).

So, my guess is that you need to get

> The crown

And give it to

> The king

Comment: Could have nothing to do with it but Rot13: gur angvbany navzny bs Fpbgynaq vf n havpbea fb znlor vg unf gb qb jvgu n xvat bs Fpbgynaq?    Again may be nothing but thought it was worth mentioning

Comment: I'm in no mood for stretching out my mediocre puzzle's solution: please google (or wikipedia) these animals. The parchment is a voting results

Comment: I meant the lion as the answer, but I really made this without thinking, so here goes your tick,